# How to build open scene graph with MinGW

Tags: cmake, mingw

I would like to install the latest open scene graph, having the latest stable version downloaded 3.0.0 and Cmake 2.8.12.2. I try to configure the sources with Cmake, generator is CodeBlocks MingGW, hitting the configure button in Cmake reports the following errors.

In configuration panel in Cmake I see that there are many variables ranging from Collada, DCMTK, Jasper Lİbrary , QT and many more. Does the OSG has dependency on all of these variables and libraries and if so how am I supposed to know the meaning of the variable if I want to install at the bear minimum. I really want to install only the core part of OSG and vaiables are bit vague for me, some of them make sense but some of them not.

```
32 bit architecture detected
searching TIFF -->tiff.h<-->libtiff<-->C:/MinGW<--
searching FREETYPE -->ft2build.h<--<freetype;freetype2311MT;freetype234;freetype234MT;freetype235;freetype237;freetype238;freetype244;<-->C:/MinGW<--
searching CURL -->curl/curl.h<-->libcurl;curllib<-->C:/MinGW<--
searching JPEG -->jpeglib.h<-->libjpeg;jpeg<-->C:/MinGW<--
searching GDAL -->gdal.h<-->gdal;gdal16<-->C:/MinGW<--
searching GLUT -->GL/glut.h<-->glut32<-->C:/MinGW<--
searching GIFLIB -->gif_lib.h<-->ungif;libungif;giflib<-->C:/MinGW<--
searching ZLIB -->zlib.h<-->z;zlib;zlib1<-->C:/MinGW<--
searching LIBXML2 -->libxml<-->libxml2<-->C:/MinGW<--
Could NOT find LibXml2 (missing:  LIBXML2_LIBRARIES LIBXML2_INCLUDE_DIR) 
Could NOT find CURL (missing:  CURL_LIBRARY CURL_INCLUDE_DIR) 
CMake Warning at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindITK.cmake:48 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file named "ITKConfig.cmake"
  provided by package "ITK".

  Add the installation prefix of "ITK" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "ITK_DIR"
  to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "ITK" provides a
  separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:465 (FIND_PACKAGE)


Could NOT find OpenAL (missing:  OPENAL_LIBRARY OPENAL_INCLUDE_DIR) 
Could NOT find SDL (missing:  SDL_LIBRARY SDL_INCLUDE_DIR) 
checking for module 'poppler-glib'
  package 'poppler-glib' not found
checking for module 'librsvg-2.0'
  package 'librsvg-2.0' not found
checking for module 'gtkglext-win32-1.0'
  package 'gtkglext-win32-1.0' not found
Found unsuitable Qt version "" from NOTFOUND
Could NOT find Qt3 (missing:  QT_QT_LIBRARY QT_INCLUDE_DIR QT_MOC_EXECUTABLE) 
Could NOT find GLUT (missing:  GLUT_glut_LIBRARY GLUT_INCLUDE_DIR) 
Could NOT find wxWidgets (missing:  wxWidgets_FOUND) 
Could NOT find JPEG (missing:  JPEG_LIBRARY JPEG_INCLUDE_DIR) 
CMake Warning (dev) at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPNG.cmake:34 (find_package):

  File C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPNG.cmake
  includes
  D:/TEST_FOLDER_asus/ENGINES/OpenSceneGraph-3.0.0/CMakeModules/FindZLIB.cmake
  (found via CMAKE_MODULE_PATH) which shadows C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake
  2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindZLIB.cmake.  This may cause errors later on
  .

  Policy CMP0017 is not set: Prefer files from the CMake module directory
  when including from there.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0017" for policy
  details.  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this
  warning.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:535 (FIND_PACKAGE)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
Could NOT find PNG (missing:  PNG_LIBRARY PNG_PNG_INCLUDE_DIR) 
Could NOT find TIFF (missing:  TIFF_LIBRARY TIFF_INCLUDE_DIR)
```

Answer (score 0):

The dependencies are all in the 3rd party dependency package, available in the downloads section of the website:

http://www.openscenegraph.org/index.php/download-section/dependencies

Although, I don't see links for a pre-built MinGW version - perhaps the VS version is compatible?  If not, you could grab them all independently or you might have to consider building under one of the express (free) versions of Visual Studio, or switching to Linux.